# Adding new Post through Custom Post Type only offers me "Slug" as an option, how do I get more?

Tags: custom-post-types

I've just added a new Custom Post Type to my WordPress site.

When I go to create a new post though, the only option I have to edit is "Slug". Normally with a regular post you would have Format, Categories, Post Tags, Featured Image, Excerpy, Send Trackbacks, Custom Fields, Discussion, and Author.

How do I get all of these options to show up for me under a Custom Post Type?

This is the code I used to create my custom post type.

```
function create_post_type() {  
        register_post_type( 'intrigue_faculty',  
                array(  
                        'labels' => array(  
                        'name' => __( 'Faculty' ),  
                        'singular_name' => __( 'Faculty' ),
                        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Faculty Member' ),
                        'new_item' => __( 'Add Faculty' ),
                        'add_new' => __( 'Add Faculty Member' ),
                        'view_item' => __( 'View Faculty Profile' ),
                        'not_found' => __( 'No faculty members found' ),
                        'search_items' => __( 'Search Faculty Members' ),
                        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Faculty Member Profile' ),
                        'description' => __( 'A collection of the profiles for Intrigue Dance Intensive faculty members.' )
                    ),  
            'public' => true,  
            'menu_position' => 5,  
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'faculty')  
            )  
    );  
}  

 add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add post-type support for those features, via [`add_post_type_support()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support)?

Use this format:

```
<?php add_post_type_support( $post_type, $supports ) ?>
```

The `$supports` argument is an array, that can include the following strings:

- 'title'
- 'editor' (content)
- 'author'
- 'thumbnail' (featured image) (current theme must also support Post Thumbnails)
- 'excerpt'
- 'trackbacks'
- 'custom-fields'
- 'comments' (also will see comment count balloon on edit screen)
- 'revisions' (will store revisions)
- 'page-attributes' (template and menu order) (hierarchical must be true)
- 'post-formats' add post formats

Note that support for these features can be registered directly, via the [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) call, using the `supports` argument-array key. See this abbreviated version of [the Codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example):

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'codex_custom_init');
function codex_custom_init() 
{
  $labels = array();
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
  ); 
  register_post_type('book',$args);
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

Using your own code:

```
<?php
function create_post_type() {  
    register_post_type( 'intrigue_faculty',  
            array(  
                'labels' => array(  
                    'name' => __( 'Faculty' ),  
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Faculty' ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Faculty Member' ),
                    'new_item' => __( 'Add Faculty' ),
                    'add_new' => __( 'Add Faculty Member' ),
                    'view_item' => __( 'View Faculty Profile' ),
                    'not_found' => __( 'No faculty members found' ),
                    'search_items' => __( 'Search Faculty Members' ),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Faculty Member Profile' ),
                    'description' => __( 'A collection of the profiles for Intrigue Dance Intensive faculty members.' )
                ),  
            'public' => true,  
            'menu_position' => 5,  
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'faculty'), // Don't forget this comma
            // ADD ME HERE; LIST WHATEVER FEATURES FOR WHICH YOU WANT TO ADD SUPPORT
            'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments') 
        )  
    );  
}  
?>
```

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with the code I used to add my custom post type. I'm having trouble figuring out where in my code I'm suppose to add your code.

Comment: See updated answer; I added the `'supports'` array argument into your code.